# how to construct a word with letters in a dropdown menu in jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have done this script to construct a word by selecting letters from dropdown menus allocated for each alphabet letter. But when changing an already selected letter from the dropdown, the display order of the letters are changed.

For ex: if you select letters from the dropdown menus and construct the word "HTML" and then if you change the letter of "H" to "X" from dropdown menu again, it displays "TMLX"(It should display XTML). 
How can I make it display in the correct order (for this example: "XTML" )

```
$('body').on('change','.engravingSelect',function(){
     //alert('it works');

    let text = '';
    let displayText = '';
    console.log(text);
    console.log("text");
     var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val(); 

      $('#EngravingSelects .engravingSelect').each(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == '') {
           text += ' ';
           displayText += '';
         } else {
           console.log('time');
           //text color change
           var current = $(this).attr('data-latter');           
           var color = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.colorDiv').find('.' + current).children("option:selected").val();   
           $(".engravingColorSelect  ."+current).css("background-color:"+color);
           text += $(this).val()+color;
           displayText += "<span style='color:"+color+";'>"+$(this).val()+"</span>";
         }
      });
```

letter drop down

```
<div class="option-wrap-family">
  <select class="engravingSelect" id="comonOption">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    .....(A to Z)
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a pretty tricky problem, as it involves splitting up Nodes. For myself, I found a project on GitHub (https://github.com/timdown/rangy) where I am using the classApplier library for purposes similar to yours. But if you are hell bent on solving this problem yourself, I wish you good luck

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeDropDown(tObj) {
    for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
      $("<option>").html(String.fromCharCode(i)).appendTo(tObj);
    }
  }

  function getWord() {
    var w = "";
    $(".engravingSelect").each(function(i, el) {
      w += $(el).val();
    });
    return w;
  }

  function getColor() {
    // var color = $(this).parent().parent().siblings('.colorDiv').find('.' + current).children("option:selected").val();   
    return "black";
  }

  function showWord() {
    var w = getWord();
    var c = getColor();
    if ($(".displayText").length) {
      $(".displayText").attr("class", "displayText " + c).html(w);
    } else {
      $("<div>", {
        class: "displayText " + c
      }).appendTo("body").html(w);
    }
  }

  $(".engravingSelect").each(function(i, el) {
    makeDropDown($(el));
    $(el).change(showWord);
  });

});
```

```css
.displayText {
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="option-wrap-family">
  <select class="engravingSelect" id="comonOption-1">
    <option></option>
  </select>
  <select class="engravingSelect" id="comonOption-2">
    <option></option>
  </select>
  <select class="engravingSelect" id="comonOption-3">
    <option></option>
  </select>
  <select class="engravingSelect" id="comonOption-4">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Without a clear and complete example, I had to make some guesses. This uses 4 drop downs, so it's easy to make changes. If you only have 1 drop down, then you may consider using an Array to store each letter, only joining them upon display. Consider that a String is just an Array of Characters, so there are ways to change a single letter in a word.

Answer (score 1):

Try my example. It uses Bootstrap and jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>My name in dropdown letters</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1CmrxMRARb6aLqgBO7yyAxTOQE2AKb9GfXnEo760AUcUmFx3ibVJJAzGytlQcNXd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</span>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <span class="dropdown-item">A</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item">S</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item">H</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item">L</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item">E</span>
        <span class="dropdown-item">Y</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** For best results, expand this snippet.

---

This means that it only works when you use HTML.

If this does not help, please tell me.

Comment: Can you explain what we're looking at here?  Just seems to be a styled drop down with no action when selecting letters.  How does this answer OPs question?